# How can I fill object before render by useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am have to fill object when component render and then show that information.
Now I am trying to do like this, but have a error, I suppose because when I try to render information object still empty.
How can I fix this issue?

```
console.log shows
{}
{}
{name: "Name"}
{name: "Name"}

export const UserCard: React.FC = () => {
let [mainInfo, setMainInfo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setMainInfo({
      name: "Name"
    })
  }, [])

  console.log(mainInfo)
  return (
    <h1>{mainInfo.name}</h1>
 );
};
```

Comment: That should work. Can you share your whole code or put that in a sandbox?

Comment: Not sure of your exact use case but if you only want to preset `mainInfo` you could remove the whole `useEffect` and move the `{name: "Name"}` to `useState({name: "Name"});`. If you mean that the error is because you don't have data yet then you would need to add a condition before rendering such as `if(mainInfo.name)`. See [React Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Sorry I don't say that i use typescript maybe does not work because of it

Comment: maybe: `<h1>{mainInfo.name || '' }</h1>`

Comment: No, doesn't work(

Comment: *"but have a error"* Could you add the error you receive to the question?

Comment: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339
return (
<h1>{mainInfo.name}</h1>

Comment: `{mainInfo?.name ?  <h1>{mainInfo.name}</h1> : null }`. React has to render something so if it's not defined render null

Answer (score 0):

[Typescript official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html)

When you set it like this:

```
let [mainInfo, setMainInfo] = useState({});
```

Typescript understands that `mainInfo` is of type `{}`. I.e: An empty object without any properties.

So when you try to access: `mainInfo.name`, Typescript is telling you that `name` does not exist on an empty object, which was the type implicitly defined for `mainInfo`.

I don't know your use-case, but you possible solution is the following:

```
interface MainInfo {
  name?: string;
}

const UserCard: React.FC = () => {
  let [mainInfo, setMainInfo] = useState<MainInfo>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMainInfo({
        name: "Name"
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return <h1>{mainInfo.name || "Loading..."}</h1>;
};
```

You need to defined the type for your `mainInfo` state. So, in the example above, I've set it as an object with an optional property `name`, as in:

```
interface MainInfo {
  name?: string
}
```

And I'm explicitly telling Typescript that `mainInfo` is of that type, by doing:

```
let [mainInfo, setMainInfo] = useState<MainInfo>({});
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-bardeen-ee99q?file=/src/App.tsx)

Now, all the errors are gone.

[image]

PS: I've added a `setTimeout` to simulate some async data. Because I don't see any other reason why you wouldn't just do: `useState({name: "NAME"});` instead of setting it inside a `useEffect`.